# Empty array error - can't pass data from an existing NSMutableArray to a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

**UPDATE**

The problem was inside the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` with the following line:

```
NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %@ .", objects[0]);
```

the new version:

```
NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %@ .", firstObject);
```

Passing the data to the mutable array was correct, i only changed the `objectAtIndex` to `firstObject`. But this block still not works properly.

**Old question:**

I have an NSMutableArray called `searchResult`, i would like to use it's first object for a PFQuery query, but the app is crashing when i'm trying to convert it to an `NSString`.

This is the error from the log:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

I know it's because an empty array, but don't understand why is the array empty. It should contain one username, because I have a search form where users can search for other users, if the search was successful i store the result in the `searchResult` mutable array. The result is listed in a table view cell, that contains the "Add Friend" button. If the user taps it, the other user should be added to it's friends. So the point is that i really really don't understand why can't i pass the existing data to the `NSString`?

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    searchResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"User", nil];   

    }

- (void)didTapButton:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    CGPoint pointInSuperview = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center  toView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInSuperview];

    NSString * contactRecipient = [searchResult objectAtIndex:0];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:contactRecipient];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %@ .", objects[0]);
            // Do something with the found objects
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

.h file

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    NSMutableArray *searchResult;
    NSString *searchRes;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *currentUser;



@end
```

Comment: You've obviously failed to add anything to `searchRuselt`. Can you show us the code where you A) initialise the array and B) add objects to it.

Comment: Using `firstObject` is safer.

Comment: One thing to not, NSArray/NSMutableArray is not a thread safe object so working on it in a background queue as your code looks like it's doing may have unexpected results.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code that initialize the mutable array. @Cocoadelica what is your advice? What would be the better way?

Comment: Where is `searchResult` defined? Is it a global variable or a property? And @CrimsonChris is correct - use the `firstObject` method.

Comment: @RoboticCat i've defined searchResult in the .h like this _NSMutableArray *searchResult;_

Comment: You have another reference in your `searchButton` method called `searchResult`. This is likely the problem. Do you know how scoping works?

Comment: There's probably some warnings like `Local declaration of 'searchResult' hides instance variable` going on.

Comment: did you allocated the searchResult array??? please show us where you setting the searchResult, its look like you getting empty result from the server

Comment: @CrimsonChris sorry, it was just a mistake. In my code i'm using a different name for that mutable array, i've just gave it a name that is easier to understand. Accidently i forget the reference from the other button.

Comment: @sabin You should always be using names that are easy to understand. Don't alter your code before posting unless you absolutely must.

Comment: Use properties instead of ivars.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is still something missing. The problem probably isn't in the code you've provided.

Comment: @CrimsonChris i missed only the irrelevant parts that works correctly (table view methods..) The **Add Friend** button works perfectly with a simple log so i'm sure the problem is that the data of **searchResult** is invisible inside the -(void)didTapButton or something like that.

Comment: On what line exactly is the error occurring?

Comment: @CrimsonChris I don't know, because it's not an error, it's crashing/freezing only when i tap the "Add Friend" button and get this from the log: _Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3052fe8b 0x3a82a6c7 0x30465e65 0xd2505 0x116c6d 0x3ad0f103 0x3ad0f0ef 0x3ad119a9 0x304fa5b9 0x304f8e85 0x30463541 0x30463323 0x3519a2eb 0x32d1a1e5 0xd0ef5 0x3ad23ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException_

Comment: That is an error. Add an "All Exceptions" breakpoint to your app to see on what line it is occuring.

Comment: @CrimsonChris the breakpoint appeared at this line: _NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %@ .", objects[0]);_ , i think it is a Parse issue and can be solved with a right block. What do you think, if there's no breakpoint at the line where i'm passing the data from searchResult to contactRecipient it means it works well?

Comment: Sounds like you're getting an empty response (which may be valid). Use `objects.firstObject` instead and make the rest of your code nil safe.

Comment: You confused everybody when you claimed that the array causing the problems was your `searchResults` array.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I know, i apologize. I was sure that the first array is the wrong array, i didn't expected that a simple NSLog can cause the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly to better help others who might stumble across this page.

Comment: Thank you @CrimsonChris for spending your time to help me figure out my problem. I've never heard about breakpoints and the firstObject version in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're getting an empty response (which may be valid). Use `objects.firstObject` instead and make the rest of your code nil safe.

Comment: Sorry, i've mixed up the names. The NSString in the searchButton called searchRes.

Comment: I've mixed it up again, sorry. I tried to edit it correctly, so the point is that the string called **searchRes** holds the data from the **searchField** and the mutable array called **searchResults** holds the result of a query.